# Falling cubes without rigid bodies

Tags: physics, unity-game-engine, collision

I have a 5x6 group of cubes that are stacked on top of each other. When the cubes should be at rest they are jittering very slightly causing a bouncing effect. Some of these cubes will disappear, and the cubes above will fall into their place. I know I can turn on Is Kinematic, or freeze the X and Y, but this causes the surrounding columns of cubes to lean slightly when I toggle them on and off.

Is there a better way I can keep these cubes in their columns without them leaning and jittering?

Comment: To the person voting to close: I would suggest that this question is perfectly valid - Unity3d may not be a common platform, but it's as popular as plenty of other minority languages/platforms that get attention here.  (There are 514 questions tagged - that seems reasonable to me!)

Comment: JonD23: despite the above, you might find better luck over at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: JonD23 - is it that your cubes aren't quite touching when they're set up?  Or is it that after your cubes above fall into place, they're not settling properly?

Comment: I was able to fix my problem shortly after I wrote the post.  My problem was that the cubes were touching their neighbors in the surrounding columns just enough to not settle.  Once I wrote my question it started to come to me.  Thanks for the help Dan.

Comment: Adding a frictional force might help, and then if you set the cubes up so they begin with small spaced between them, as they fall this may/should dampen the jittering effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

-See if you are using a physic material, "Metal" would be best for you.

-Make the weight of the boxes more

-Make sure that their collision boxes aren't overlapping, you can try to set the collision detection to continuous, although, be aware that this uses more processing power.

Cheers!